Deployment error while installing standalone version via docker
I am trying to install the standalone version using this docker-compose file: https://lab.civicrm.org/michaelmcandrew/civioneclick-docker/-/blob/main/compose.example.yaml?ref_type=heads
However, I am getting an deployment error:

Deployment error
Failed to deploy a stack: web Pulling web Error pull access denied for civicrm-standalone-nightly, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied Error response from daemon: pull access denied for civicrm-standalone-nightly, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied

Does someone have an idea where this could come from? What would be the correct image name to add in the docker-compose file?

You're using a docker compose file called "compose.example.yaml" - that's not intended as something you can just run.
Also, I think you're using an old repo, you probably want to be using a new one here: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-docker
And finally, the specific issue you met was that you had no image by the name of "civicrm-standalone-nightly" (which is the image name in that example compose file). That tells me you probably didn't see this note in the readme:

Note: until these images are published on docker hub, you will need to
start by building them locally. You can do by running php build.php
--skip-push. See Management below for more details.

